# Change git hub repository to main folder (i.s.o subfolder)

Tags: git, github

I am fairly new to git hub and I am working with two people on a repository. Currently I have a (local) repository at the following location:

```
C:\Users\Name\main_folder\sub_folder_9\
```

Now, in the `main_folder` there are a lot of sub_folders. We are now only sharing/pushing the information that is in `sub_folder_9`, but we want to 'move' the directory up. So we want to set up a repository in `main_folder`, such that all sub_folders are pushed and pulled whenever we use Git Bash. And we would like to use the same repository that we currently have (on the github.com site), so we do not have to set up a new one.

How can I achieve this?

I know I might have used wrong verbology, I am sorry for that but I hope my question still makes sense.

Comment: Destroy the repo and start over?

Comment: @matt, that is of course a possibility. I just hoped there was a better solution so we do not have to re-instate the git hub via the Bash.

Comment: What about moving the .git folder?

Comment: can I just move the (hidden) .git folder and then push from that folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said in your comment : yes, you can move the `.git` folder one level up, and then push.

More precisely :

```
# move the .git folder one level up :
mv .git ../
cd ../

# if you want, you can create a separate commit which clearly moves only sub_folder_9 :
git add sub_folder_9
git commit

# add the remainder of your main_repo folder :
git add *
git commit
```

and then push.

Comment: Thank you! Will do!